# Best folder for uploading files in IIS

Tags: iis, upload

What is the best / recommended folder to use as staging area for file uploads in IIS? I know there is App_Data but that is supposed to be for databases or xml files, but I never saw a firm recommendation where to put uploaded files.

EDIT - Telerik puts files under App_Data. I looks like the best place.